# Why are these two userChrome.css files incompatible?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, css

This userChrome.css does what I want it to. In particular, it makes me able to edit bookmark URLs from the blue star menu.

```
/* userChrome.css */

@namespace xul "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul";
@namespace html "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

/* Add option to edit bookmark URLs under blue star menu */
#editBMPanel_locationRow {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

This userChrome.css is my usual and does many things that I want it to, such as making my bookmarks take up far less room in their toolbar.

```
/*@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");*/
@namespace xul "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul";
@namespace html "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
.bookmark-item{
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important; 
}
toolbarbutton.bookmark-item .toolbarbutton-text{
    display: none !important;
}
toolbarbutton.bookmark-item .toolbarbutton-icon{
    margin-left: 2px !important;
}
#PlacesToolbarItems > .bookmark-item > .toolbarbutton-icon[label]:not([label=""]) {
    margin-inline-end: 2px !important;
}
toolbarbutton.subviewbutton.subviewbutton-iconic .toolbarbutton-text{
    display: -moz-box !important;
}
/* --- [1] --- */
toolbarbutton.bookmark-item:hover:not(.subviewbutton):not([disabled="true"]):not([open]) .toolbarbutton-text{
    display: -moz-box !important;
}
/* Hide Giant Thumbnail and Favicon */
#editBookmarkPanelImage,
*|div#editBookmarkPanelFaviconContainer {
  display: none !important;
}

/* fix right click menu disappearing on highlighted text */
*#contentAreaContextMenu { margin: 12px 0 0 12px };
```

But when I mix them by appending

```
/* Add option to edit bookmark URLs under blue star menu */
#editBMPanel_locationRow, #editBMPanel_keywordRow {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

to the end of the previous CSS file, I do not gain the ability to edit URLs from the blue star menu.

Each of these work just fine independently, but the bookmark editing - and only the bookmark editing - does not work when I mix them. Is there any clear reason for this incompatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a new profile in Firefox with your userChrome.css and the extra `#editBMPanel_locationRow` entry at the bottom. I observed your behaviour of the pieces not showing up in the bookmark modal/dialog. I then placed it above the `*#contentAreaContextMenu` entry, and then the pieces showed up! Which told me the problem was probably the last entry in the CSS. And indeed, there is a subtle typo:

```
/* fix right click menu disappearing on highlighted text */
*#contentAreaContextMenu { margin: 12px 0 0 12px };
```

That semicolon at the end of the second line should be **inside** the braces. When I fix that and have your `#editBMPanel_locationRow` entry at the bottom, it works:

```
/*@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");*/
@namespace xul "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul";
@namespace html "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
.bookmark-item{
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important; 
}
toolbarbutton.bookmark-item .toolbarbutton-text{
    display: none !important;
}
toolbarbutton.bookmark-item .toolbarbutton-icon{
    margin-left: 2px !important;
}
#PlacesToolbarItems > .bookmark-item > .toolbarbutton-icon[label]:not([label=""]) {
    margin-inline-end: 2px !important;
}
toolbarbutton.subviewbutton.subviewbutton-iconic .toolbarbutton-text{
    display: -moz-box !important;
}
/* --- [1] --- */
toolbarbutton.bookmark-item:hover:not(.subviewbutton):not([disabled="true"]):not([open]) .toolbarbutton-text{
    display: -moz-box !important;
}
/* Hide Giant Thumbnail and Favicon */
#editBookmarkPanelImage,
*|div#editBookmarkPanelFaviconContainer {
  display: none !important;
}

/* fix right click menu disappearing on highlighted text */
*#contentAreaContextMenu { margin: 12px 0 0 12px ;}

/* Add option to edit bookmark URLs under blue star menu */
#editBMPanel_locationRow, #editBMPanel_keywordRow {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

A screenshot from the test profile:

[image]

Comment: Does this suggest that the `*#contentAreaContextMenu` call has always done nothing?

Comment: That depends on how the parser treats the syntax error. But with my fiddling, anything *after* a syntax error like that was not picked up, but the rule where it happened still applied.